# Visualizing features from properties of a feature collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, attribute-joins, features, visualisation, properties

I would like to know how to visualize features (points)  situated in the properties of feature collection that was obtained after applying 'spatial joins' on  primary collection ( protected areas (Yosemite National Park))and secondary collection (power plants) in GEE?

https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/joins_spatial

Answer (score 0):

You only need to add following lines at the bottom of the code:

```
var points = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.List(spatialJoined.first().get('points')));

print(points);

Map.centerObject(primary, 8);
Map.addLayer(primary);
Map.addLayer(points);
```

Complete code can be accessed [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/97b682b3e1b87627af43b81aa863841d) and, after running it, the result is obtained as follows. There are all the power plants within 100 kilometers of Yosemite National Park, USA.

[image]